# Create a custom html template using forms in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I've been going over the docs and some StackOverflow examples but I'm still having a little trouble. In Django I created a form, the view renders it and I have it displayed as form.as_p in the HTML template. This works perfectly, but I would like to be able to customize my HTML template instead of having it displayed as form.as_p. Any examples on how to do so?

So far I have the following.

View:

```
@login_required
def register(request):

    info = Content.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=info)

        if form.is_valid():
            info = form.save(commit=False)
            info.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/portal/register')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm(instance=info)

        return render(request, 'portal/register.html', {'form': form, 'gallery': info})
```

Form:

```
class UploadFileForm(ModelForm):

    logo = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    image1 = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    terms = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ['user', 'logo', 'image1', 'terms']
```

Model:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    terms = models.CharField(max_length="256", blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

HTML Template:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    {% if gallery.logo %}
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="/media/{{ gallery.logo }}" alt="">
                    {% else %}
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="/media/images/placeholder.png" alt="">
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
                <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" multiple>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    {% if gallery.image1 %}
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="image1" src="/media/{{ gallery.image1 }}" alt="">
                    {% else %}
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="image1" src="/media/images/placeholder.png" alt="">
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
                <input type="file" name="image1" id="image1" multiple>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="terms" id="terms" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="terms" value="{{ gallery.terms }}">
            </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: docs cover it pretty well https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, look into [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3). It will save you a lot of pain. See also [Django Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Sorry, I should of explained better. I want to put input wherever I would like in the HTML and have it upload to the model form.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can loop on the form fields by doing the following

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        <label> 
            {{ field.label_tag }}
        </label>
       <div>
           {{ field }}
       </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you can add class to the div and label tags and style the form fields

You can also use Django Widget Tweaks to add classed to the form fields.

Click [here](https://bixly.com/blog/easy-django-form-customization-using-django-widget-tweaks/) to read in more details

By using widget tweaks you simply find the field in which you want to add the class by doing this

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{{ form.name|add_class:"inputContact volunteer" }}
```

Comment: bixly link broken :(

Answer (score 2):

You can [render the fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually):

> We don’t have to let Django unpack the form’s fields; we can do it
>   manually if we like (allowing us to reorder the fields, for example).
>   Each field is available as an attribute of the form using {{
>   form.name_of_field }}, and in a Django template, will be rendered
>   appropriately.

Example from the documentation:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
```

As I said in the comments, see also [Django Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You can achieve the same without so much markup.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. How would I submit the form fields manually? an example being I want a certain input that I have created in HTML to upload to a specific model field?

Comment: You control that with the `name` attribute of the `input` fields. That's `{{ field.html_name }}` if you use iterate the fields in the form.

Comment: How would I create a custom input field?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can create custom widgets, but for what you are doing you just have to write HTML, using the field's attributes if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Paulo. I guess I am trying to figure out how to write HTML using the attributes I wish and relating that to my view. Do you by chance know of a working example of that method?